# How to set tint color on pdf asset in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, uiimageview, assets

I created a new image set, set "Scales" as "Single Scale" and placed my PDF asset in. Afterwards, I set "Render as" to "Template Image" and when I set a UIImageView to display my asset, it shows up but I cannot change the tint color in storyboard. Does anyone know what I need to do in order to be able to modify the tint color on a PDF vector asset in Xcode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the `UIImageView's` image in code doesn't produce this problem.

There is a bug in Xcode which prevents `UIImageView` from coloring its template image in tint color when loaded from Interface Builder. See: [rdar://18448072](http://openradar.appspot.com/18448072)

If you don't want to set the image in code, the most elegant solution I found was creating the following extension for `UIImageView`:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        tintColorDidChange()
    }
}
```

Props to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/buechner/3b97000a6570a2bfbc99c005cb010bac).